# mySQL - Set isolation level using PHP's mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, isolation-level

How do I set the isolation level of a transaction to 'SERIALIZABLE' in PHP using mysqli? I have looked everywhere and I can't find any information on it.

[Here](http://www.learn-mysql-tutorial.com/Transactions.cfm) is an explanation of the isolation levels.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just set the isolation level in a query before you run your statements. This assume that you do everything using the same session:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$mysqli->query("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE");
...
```

You may also want to turn off [autocommit](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) before hand since it changes the way [serializable isolation works](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable).

Comment: Is there some more information regarding the 'You may also want to turn off autocommit before hand since it changes the way serializable isolation works.' comment?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175550/mysql-5-7-scope-of-set-transaction-isolation-level-for-select

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$mysqli->query("SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE");
```

Long Answer: Unless you use the **SESSION** or **GLOBAL** modifier, setting the transaction level will only apply to the very next query.

tldr;

According to the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html) with InnoDB tables:

> Without any SESSION or GLOBAL keyword:
>
> The statement applies only to the next single transaction performed
>   within the session.
>
> Subsequent transactions revert to using the session value of the named
>   characteristics.
>
> *The statement is not permitted within transactions*

Note that setting the `GLOBAL` flag will affect all *subsequent* queries  Existing sessions will not be affected.