# wait to read a row when there is a lock on it -- transaction isolation

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I want to lock a table row so that any other reading operations on that row will wait until the lock is released, and I want to avoid to have a lock on the entire table.

I have the following table (InnoDB)

```
CREATE TABLE account_balance (
    account INTEGER UNIQUE, 
    balance INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (account)
);
```

I execute the following transaction to obtain a lock on a row

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT balance FROM account_balance WHERE account = 1 FOR UPDATE;
SELECT SLEEP(10);
COMMIT;
```

And I would like the following query to wait for the lock to be released

```
SELECT balance FROM account_balance WHERE account = 1;
```

To do it, the only way I found is to run the SELECT as follow

```
SET autocommit = 0; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE; SELECT ....;
```

It will wait for the lock to be released but I should prefix every `SELECT` with autocommit and isolation level settings for this table.

Is there a way to configure `autocommit=0` and `transaction-isolation = SERIALIZABLE` **ONLY** at table level?

I know that I could set

```
[mysqld]
transaction-isolation = SERIALIZABLE
autocommit = 0
```

in `my.cnf`, but I do not want to affect other operations done on other tables and schemas.

refs:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for an interesting question. From what host language are you connecting to MySQL?

Comment: Hi Ollie, thanks for your reply. There will be more than one client reading from that table, and they could be written in different languages (PHP & JS). I'm looking for a "server side" solution because I'd like to enforce it regardless of the language one uses to make the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

The autocommit and transaction-isolation settings are associated not with any table, but with each connection to MySQL.

Most language bindings have a directly callable function to enable or disable autocommit. For example, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php

You can set the transaction isolation level the way you have done. Once you set that for a connection, it will remain set.  See this for example. [mySQL - Set isolation level using PHP's mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731696/mysql-set-isolation-level-using-phps-mysqli)

It's generally good practice to put such mode-setting code immediately after the code that establishes the connection, so the modes are predictable for the rest of your application.